What Is The Proper Way To Invoke a Generic Interface Method of a Class Through Reflection?
I feel like maybe I'm missing an intermediate step. Here's what I'm attempting.
If I try this:
typeof(IMessageHandler<>)
  .GetMethod("HandleAsync")! 
  .MakeGenericMethod(handlerInfo.HandledMessageType!)       
  .Invoke(incomingMessageHandler, 
  [consumerContext.Message, consumerContext]);

...then I get the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask HandleAsync(TMessage, Namespace.IConsumeContext) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

While if I try this:
typeof(IMessageHandler<>)
  .GetMethod("HandleAsync")! 
  //.MakeGenericMethod(handlerInfo.HandledMessageType!)       
  .Invoke(incomingMessageHandler, 
  [consumerContext.Message, consumerContext]);

...I get the error:

Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.


Based on the provided info - it's type which is generic/has generic parameters, not the method, so construct the type (i.e. MakeGenericType):
typeof(IMessageHandler<>)
  .MakeGenericType(handlerInfo.HandledMessageType!) 
  .GetMethod("HandleAsync")! 
  .Invoke(...)


Ah, silly me. That was it.
Thanks for the second set of eyes.
